# I wanna understand why this syntax works, and how

Tags: actionscript-3

I've seen a very strange thing that i know it works, but i can't seem to understand exactly why and how this works.

i have a line of code that reads this:

```
_game._requestedState = new  (FlxU.getClass(FlxU.getClassName(_game._state,false)))();
```

Ok, so what i can see here, is, i'm invoking an annonymous constructor, by reflection. Is that it?

- A simple **yes** would do as an answer.
- A **no with an explanation** about how and why this works would be perfect.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such thing as an anonymous constructor.

The method is called FlxU.getClass**Name**, which makes it clear that there is in fact a name involved. It takes some `_game._state`, get's a class name from it and then gets the actual class from that name.

This is similar to `getDefinitionByName()`, which it likely uses internally.

Comment: This first parenthesis might be what got me a little crazy about this
new (FlxU.getClass(FlxU.getClassName(_game._state,false)))()

Thanks :)

Comment: @Tácio Mendes I'm not sure if all paragenesis are necessary. Try to remove them and see if it still compilers and works as expected.